# How to dynamically change the steps of a material stepper when pressing a checkbox

Tags: .net, angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I am developing a modal window (Angular 7 +  Material Angular solution)that pressing a checkbox has to change the steps of the stepper, from the 5 that are original to only 3, with this it implies that the last step is only a confirmation of the registered information.

I haven't been able to make my "next" button switch between steps well when changing steps (which I already do well), in fact if I press "back" it changes and when I go back to the next step, the button does let me go to the confirmation mentioned above.

any advice to do this?

Original Modal:
[image]

My Conditional Field:

[image]

Modal After Press Conditional Field

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add listener to the checkbox change event and on that you can move next or previous stepper using below code.

on HTML

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper **#stepper**>


import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material/stepper';

goBack(stepper: MatStepper){
    stepper.previous();
}

goForward(stepper: MatStepper){
     stepper.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable in your .ts

```
 skip:boolean=false;
```

You has a checkbox with `[(ngModel)]`. Be carefull, as possible is enclosed in a formGroup you should use `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"`

```
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="skip" 
                             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" />Skip
  </label>


  //or using a mat-checkbox

  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="skip" 
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" >Skip
  </mat-checkbox>
```

Now simply use a *ngIf

```
<mat-step *ngIf="!skip" [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" >
  ...
</mat-step>
```

If the "skip" is a formControl of your FormGroup you simply use

```
<mat-step *ngIf="!myform.get('skip').value" 
       [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" >
```